# How to return and format an array in php by using curl

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, curl

I know this maybe an easy question but I am still stuck here.

I am calling an API, this is my code:

```
   $access_token = 'asdfasdfasdfasdf';
   $uid = '12345678';
   $url = 'https://api.asd.com/2/statuses/user_timeline/ids.json?uid='.$uid.'&access_token='.$access_token.'&count=5';
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,false);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
   $content=curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   echo $content;
```

This is what I got:

```
{
    "statuses":"4023805771256802","4023694609717194","4021770053107357","4021769599890997","4021769217975680"],
    "marks":[],
    "hasvisible":false,
    "previous_cursor":0,
    "next_cursor":0,
    "total_number":94,
    "interval":0,
    "uve_blank":0
}
```

What I want is having an array of 'statuses' only, because I want to use the data in 'statuses' only.

Anyone can give me a hint? I will be really appreciated.

Comment: When you say, "This is what I got", is that a text string that is returned from your curl request?  If so, just json_decode the string with second param TRUE, e.g. $array = json_decode(your_text_string, TRUE)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is [JSON](http://json.org/) data...use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert to array

```
$arr = json_decode($content, TRUE);

$statuses = $arr['statuses'];
```

Comment: Thank you soo much, I tried json_decode and I thought it's not working, but the fact is I made a very silly mistake. Now I made it, silly me.

Comment: in future it really is better to show what you tried and let people help you fix your attempts than to just ask "how do I...".